# Copy PDF file to iBooks library

Tags: iphone, ios, pdf, ibooks

I'm developing a sample app that user can read pdf file, pdf files in my app bundle and i use web view to read these files. Now i want to add a button that allow user click to and copy pdf file to iBooks library, that means when user perform this action, after that, when user opens iBooks app, this PDF file is already available in library of iBooks. Any idea for this problem, plz helps me, thanks alot.
PS: i want to make as [this link](http://www.iphonelife.com/blog/7032/how-put-your-pdf-files-ibooks), but i dont want open pdf file immediately in iBooks when user click button, i just want when user open ibooks after that anytime, user can see this pdf book in book shelf

Comment: If there isn't an API for it, don't bother trying.

Comment: i don't want to open pdf file in iBooks immediately, i just want copy this pdf file to some where in my ipad and then when user open iBooks app, this pdf file is already available in library of iBooks

Comment: Cole's right. If you do it without using an API, Apple will make a rule to stop you doing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not an API available for directly adding content to iBooks, unfortunately.

How it works is your app uses a `UIDocumentInteractionController` to present the user with the ability to open the PDF in an application that supports the file type that you specify to the controller.  One of those apps would be iBooks, if it is installed on the user's device.

Additional Resources:

- [UIDocumentInteractionController sample application from developer.apple.com](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/DocInteraction/DocInteraction.zip)
- [UIDocumentInteractionController Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDocumentInteractionController_class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Hi Wayne, If a pdf file is downloaded using safari it is appeared in iBooks menu automatically. Isn't it possible that I download a pdf using my application and make the pdf file appear automatically in iBooks. If not How can safari do that?

Comment: @BurakKarasoy you will find that Apple often give themselves APIs that we do not have access to...

Comment: thank you Wayne, Safari can access those APIs but we can not ?